# Is there a way to embed C# code into a Lua script?

Tags: c#, lua

I have a program which forces Lua as a choice for programming plugins. I'd like to take some existing C# code, and use it in this program. Is this possible?

I should add that I know one can easily embed Lua code into C#, but I haven't found the reverse anywhere. Thanks guys!

Comment: Do you have control of the program? If not, then the answer is probably no.

Comment: Is there maybe a published way to let Lua talk to COM objects?

Comment: @flq, see [LuaCOM](http://www.tecgraf.puc-rio.br/~rcerq/luacom/), which is included in [Lua for Windows](http://code.google.com/p/luaforwindows/).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take a look at [LuaInteface](http://code.google.com/p/luainterface/):

> LuaInterface is a way for Lua programs to access the CLR (Common Language Runtime), otherwise known as .NET in the Windows world and Mono on Linux.

I'm not sure that's the official site, and there are multiple versions/forks (like [MonoLuaInterface](https://github.com/stevedonovan/MonoLuaInterface)). Just search for LuaInterface.

Answer (score 0):

Lua is not compilable language, insteed of C#. So i see no way to embed lower lang onto script language :)

Comment: Why not? VBScript or Powershell can talk to C# types without much problem!

Comment: I think embedded language should be embedded to langs like c#,c++, etc. and not vice versa. That's not the language useing for.

Comment: Both C# and Lua compile to byte codes for a virtual machine. There are even JIT compilers for both. With LuaInterface, it is certainly possible to call code written in C#, and IIRC it is also possible for C# to call back into the Lua side. There is a similar package for COM.